# Nsight 2.2 sometimes works sometimes doesn't

Tags: debugging, cuda, gpu

I have problem about Parallel Nsight 2.2 debugger. It is very strange and I don't know how to describe it. Anyway, It works sometimes and sometimes doesn't.

What I observed is, that it works with dynamic array(this array has no effect on cuda_kernels or any other functon like cudaMemcpy atc...) named with 3 elements. And this is importnat... If I set size on 4+, it just falls down, no errors, nothing just fall down.

Interesting fact is, that if I run it normally via normal debugger hole program works correctly with right results. Also interesting fact is, that when set this array as static

unsigned topology[4];

and set in same values Nsight debugger works but very slowly.

So first of all I commented all cuda source code (like kernels and all cuda functions) but still same - it falls down. So I started to comment more host_code and I found loop (in host code) which does this creepy thing. So when program in Nsght-debug reach loop(under text) it falls down, BUT, when I write command in this loop to print number of each loop on screen, it runs, loop is finished, hole program is finished and then debugger told me:

Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: 
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c
Line: 1322

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

.... I don't even have disk f ... so wtf???

Anyway, on normal debugger it runs fine and with right results.

This is mentioned loop and dynamic array *topology:

```
unsigned *topology;
unsigned numberOfLayersInput = 5;
topology = new unsigned [numberOfLayersInput];

topology[0] = 784;
topology[1] = 1000;
topology[2] = 800;
topology[3] = 300;
topology[4] = 10;

kernelTopology_ *topologyOfKernels;
topologyOfKernels = new kernelTopology_ [numberOfLayersInput - 1];
for (int i = 0, numberOfThreads; i < numberOfLayersInput; i++)
{
    cout <<i << endl;   // this is the added line!
    numberOfThreads = fixedTopology[i];
    topologyOfKernels[i].size = numberOfThreads;

    if(numberOfThreads > THREADS_PER_BLOCK)
        topologyOfKernels[i].BLOCK_SIZE = THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
    else topologyOfKernels[i].BLOCK_SIZE = numberOfThreads;

    if(numberOfThreads <= THREADS_PER_BLOCK)
        topologyOfKernels[i].GRID_SIZE = 1;
    else if(fixedTopology[i] % topologyOfKernels[i].BLOCK_SIZE == 0)
        topologyOfKernels[i].GRID_SIZE = fixedTopology[i] / topologyOfKernels[i].BLOCK_SIZE;
    else        
        topologyOfKernels[i].GRID_SIZE = (fixedTopology[i] / topologyOfKernels[i].BLOCK_SIZE) + 1;
}
```

I can't see any mistakes in this code... also normal debugger has no problem with it.

I have reinstalled graphics drivers, CUDA toolkit, CUDA SDK and Paralell Nsight but it does same creepy things. By the way I use Win 7 64 bit and VS2010.

Does have anyone any ideas what I should do with this?

Please, let me know if someone has any idea :)

Comment: The error Debug Assertion Failed! Program: File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c Line: 1322 is from the Microsoft C runtime. I think topologyOfKernels = new kernelTopology_ [numberOfLayersInput - 1]; should be allocating numberofLayersInput element not numberofLayersInput - 1. If you provide a full reproducible the development team can look into the issue.

Comment: it seems like solution for my problem. wow thank you, I didn't see it. 

thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
Debug Assertion Failed! Program: File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c Line: 1322
```

is from the Microsoft C runtime function [_CrtIsValidHeapPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys6cfhhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The default debug build adds additional heap and stack checks into the code. This function is used to verify that a specified pointer is in the local heap. The path f:... is the location of the source file in the C runtime. This function is  at the time Microsoft built the library.

The assertion indicates an out of bounds memory access. The cause of the error appears to be incorrect allocation of *topologyOfKernels*.

```
corruption.topologyOfKernels = new kernelTopology_ [numberOfLayersInput - 1];
```

should be allocating *numberofLayersInput* elements.

```
corruption.topologyOfKernels = new kernelTopology_ [numberOfLayersInput];
```